omnisharp-roslyn server using python
We are building an LSP client using omnisharp-roslyn server in python using BaseLanguageClient from pygls.
Once I start the server, using client.start_io which utilizes stdin version of omnisharp-roslyn. We are unable to get any response even the initialization request in async version doesn't get the response and awaits forever.
Here is csharp_lsp_client.py:
import asyncio
import logging
from lsprotocol.types import InitializeParams, DidOpenTextDocumentParams, TextDocumentItem, ClientCapabilities, CallHierarchyOutgoingCallsParams, CallHierarchyItem, SymbolKind, Range, Position, DefinitionParams, DocumentSymbolParams, TextDocumentIdentifier, DocumentHighlightParams
from pygls.lsp.client import BaseLanguageClient

# Configure logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

async def main():
    client = BaseLanguageClient('C Sharp', '2.0')
    await client.start_io(
        "omnisharp",
        "-lsp",
        "-s",
        r"bloop_in_python\omnisharp-roslyn", # complete path, this is just for sample
    )
    print('started')
    # Initialize the client
    initialize_result = await client.initialize_async(InitializeParams(ClientCapabilities()))
    print(initialize_result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

